# Code Blocks 16.01 can't find headers

Tags: c++, codeblocks, header-files

code blocks 16.01 can't find headers.
I write some c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
.....
int main()
{
    ...
}
```

it can be compiled without any errors or warnings, and run perfectly. But when I right-click the iostream then choose open iostream, it says that "Not found: iostream"
why? how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found that it's a matter of setting.
We should set the path of compiler as "...\codeblocks\MinGW\" rather than "...\codeblocks\MinGW\bin\". At meantime we should add an environment variable which is "...\codeblocks\MinGW\bin"

Answer (score -2):

You're using `int main` function. In other words, it is waiting for a return of an integer. You can also solve this by just using `void main` function.

Comment: This is wrong for two reasons. (1) A failure to return a value is not the error that he is getting. He has intentionally elided the code in the question with ellipses (`...`) so you can't see what he is doing. For all you know, it ends with `return 0;` (2) `void main` is not standard C++, so you cannot simply change the signature of the function.

Comment: I meant that the code is RIGHT, and it's not important what codes they are. I said they CAN be compiled, and run PERFECTLY. But when I right-click the <iostream> in the EDITOR, then choose OPEN iostream, then Codeblocks says "Not found: iostream". And now I've solved it. Thank you guys.